# Calling key/value in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm pretty sure I'm just overthinking this but I can't think of any other ways right now.

I have a hidden field that contains image_ids. The value of the hidden field looks like "1076,1077,1078"

In my Controller, I am doing this:

```
    // get the value from hidden field
    $image_string = $this->input->post('images');

    // create array from comma separated string
    $images = explode(',', $image_string);

    $image = array();

    // get image data from the database, returns an array of the database row
    foreach ($images as $id) {
      $image[$id] = $this->file_model->get_image_data($id);
    }

   print_r($image);
```

When I do the `print_r(image);` at the end, I get this:

```
Array (
 [0] => stdClass Object ( [image_id] => 1076 )
 [1] => stdClass Object ( [image_id] => 1077 )
 [2] => stdClass Object ( [image_id] => 1078 )
)
```

This is where I'm stuck. I need to do another foreach to echo out each image_id, but I can't figure out how to call it. What should the 2nd foreach look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of objects, so all you need is:

```
foreach( $image as $obj) {
    echo $obj->image_id;
}
```

Comment: lol wow, I was definitely overthinking this. thanks, that's exactly what I needed